# google glass software version update and run gdk sample

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have a glass and it's software version is XE12.1 i think it's very old one.
so i want to upgrade my glass software version. I tried steps mentioned in google developer page, it said when glass meet four conditions it will automatically update. but it didn't.

so my question is, is there any way for updating software manually?

and 
when i run GDK samples, like a Compass or timer. eclipse said all apk is installed. but i couldn't find it anywhere. In the card tap or void command tap, it doesn't appear.

How can i get this sampels?

---

and when i saw device info. it said XE12.1 up to date.

Comment: Does your glass show the new updates availability?

Comment: no it said up to date.

Comment: Sounds like you tried/did unlock or root your Glass which automatically disables updates. If this the case, then you have to manually flash the update via factory images.

Comment: Is your glass connected to wi-fi, if not it will show that there are no updates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For product issues such as failing to apply an OTA update, please contact your guide for support (Support tab on the MyGlass website).